# Convert OpenCV video to Streamlit video in-memory

Tags: python, opencv, streamlit

I have a list of image frames `frames` that I would like to be able to display in Streamlit application: `st.video(frames_converted)`.

#### Challenges:

- Streamlit takes HTML5 and video requires H264 encoding
- Want to complete all processing in-memory (as opposed to the much more common saving to temporary file

#### Current attempt:

```py
## Convert frames to video for streamlit
height, width, layers = frames[0].shape
codec = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
fps = 1
video = cv.VideoWriter("temp_video",codec, fps, (width,height)) # Initialize video object
for frame in frames:
    video.write(frame)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()

st.video(video)
```

#### Current Blocker

```
RuntimeError: Invalid binary data format: <class 'cv2.VideoWriter'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may encode an "in memory" MP4 video using [PyAV](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV) as described in my [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73627720/4926757) - the video is stored in `BytesIO` object.
We may pass the BytesIO object as input to Streamlit (or convert the BytesIO object to bytes array and use the array as input).

---

Code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2  # OpenCV is used only for writing text on image (for testing).
import av
import io
import streamlit as st

n_frmaes = 100  # Select number of frames (for testing).

width, height, fps = 192, 108, 10  # Select video resolution and framerate.

output_memory_file = io.BytesIO()  # Create BytesIO "in memory file".

output = av.open(output_memory_file, 'w', format="mp4")  # Open "in memory file" as MP4 video output
stream = output.add_stream('h264', str(fps))  # Add H.264 video stream to the MP4 container, with framerate = fps.
stream.width = width  # Set frame width
stream.height = height  # Set frame height
#stream.pix_fmt = 'yuv444p'   # Select yuv444p pixel format (better quality than default yuv420p).
stream.pix_fmt = 'yuv420p'   # Select yuv420p pixel format for wider compatibility.
stream.options = {'crf': '17'}  # Select low crf for high quality (the price is larger file size).


def make_sample_image(i):
    """ Build synthetic "raw BGR" image for testing """
    p = width//60
    img = np.full((height, width, 3), 60, np.uint8)
    cv2.putText(img, str(i+1), (width//2-p*10*len(str(i+1)), height//2+p*10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, p, (255, 30, 30), p*2)  # Blue number
    return img


# Iterate the created images, encode and write to MP4 memory file.
for i in range(n_frmaes):
    img = make_sample_image(i)  # Create OpenCV image for testing (resolution 192x108, pixel format BGR).
    frame = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(img, format='bgr24')  # Convert image from NumPy Array to frame.
    packet = stream.encode(frame)  # Encode video frame
    output.mux(packet)  # "Mux" the encoded frame (add the encoded frame to MP4 file).

# Flush the encoder
packet = stream.encode(None)
output.mux(packet)
output.close()

output_memory_file.seek(0)  # Seek to the beginning of the BytesIO.
#video_bytes = output_memory_file.read()  # Convert BytesIO to bytes array
#st.video(video_bytes)
st.video(output_memory_file)  # Streamlit supports BytesIO object - we don't have to convert it to bytes array.

# Write BytesIO from RAM to file, for testing:
#with open("output.mp4", "wb") as f:
#    f.write(output_memory_file.getbuffer())
#video_file = open('output.mp4', 'rb')
#video_bytes = video_file.read()
#st.video(video_bytes)
```

---

We can't use `cv.VideoWriter`, because it does not support in-memory video encoding (`cv.VideoWriter` requires a "true file").

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be along the right track although the provided code doesn't display a playable video in streamlit.

Comment: I tested my code before posting the answer. It worked when I executed `streamlit run C:\Tmp\PyAvImagesToMP4ToStreamlit.py` from Windows shell. The video is shown in my Chrome browser. Is there a better way for testing?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a better way to test. I'm running on macbook pro with python 3.8, opencv headless 4.6. There error I'm getting is that the file is corrupt. Seems like a version/platform issue. I'll continue testing...

Comment: What brawser are you using? Your brawser may not support yuv444, try `yuv420p` instead. There may also be H.264 profile limitation (like "main profile"), or some missing tag, that macOS  brawser requires.

Comment: It wasn't a browser issue I don't think. Tried safari, chrome and firefox. But looks like yuv420p works thanks! I'd your code but says suggestion box is full. Can check answered then.

Comment: I updated the answer. I also realized we can pass the BytesIO as argument to `st.video` (there is no need to convert from BytesIO to bytes array).