# Creating video from images using PyAV

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, pyav

I am trying to write a function that creates a new MP4 video from a set of frames taken from another video. The frames will be given in `PIL.Image` format and is often cropped to include only a part of the input video, but all images will have the same dimension.

What I have tried:

```py
def modify_image(img):
    return img

test_input = av.open('input_vid.mp4')
test_output =av.open('output_vid.mp4', 'w')

in_stream = test_input.streams.video[0]
out_stream = test_output.add_stream(template=in_stream)

for frame in test_input.decode(in_stream):
    img_frame = frame.to_image()

    # Some possible modifications to img_frame...
    img_frame = modify_image(img_frame)

    out_frame = av.VideoFrame.from_image(img_frame)
    out_packet = out_stream.encode(out_frame)
    print(out_packet)

     
test_input.close()
test_output.close()
```

And the error that I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 11
      8     img_frame = frame.to_image()
     10     out_frame = av.VideoFrame.from_image(img_frame)
---> 11     out_packet = out_stream.encode(out_frame)
     12     print(out_packet)
     15 test_input.close()

File av\stream.pyx:153, in av.stream.Stream.encode()

File av\codec\context.pyx:490, in av.codec.context.CodecContext.encode()

File av\frame.pyx:52, in av.frame.Frame._rebase_time()

ValueError: Cannot rebase to zero time.
```

I followed the answer given in [How to create a video out of frames without saving it to disk using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73627720/13150854), and met with the same issue.

Comparing the original VideoFrame and the VideoFrame created from the image, I found that the `pts` value of the new frames are saved as `None` instead of integer values. Overwriting the `pts` value of the new frame with the original values still causes the same error, and overwriting the `dts` value of the new frame gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: attribute 'dts' of 'av.frame.Frame' objects is not writable
```

Is there a way to modify the `dts` value, or possibly another method to create a video from a set of `PIL.Image` objects?

Comment: DTS means "decode timestamp". you want to assign PTS (presentation timestamp)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz assigning PTS with the values found in the original video still causes the same error.

Comment: hmm ok I haven't looked too deeply into your code. please compare to https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/main/examples/numpy/generate_video_with_pts.py and check if you're missing a frame rate or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `add_stream(template=in_stream)` is only documented in the [Remuxing example](https://pyav.org/docs/develop/cookbook/basics.html#remuxing).
It's probably possible to use `template=in_stream` when re-encoding, but we have to set the time-base, and set the PTS timestamp of each encoded packet.
I found a discussion [here](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/issues/730) (I didn't try it).

Instead of using `template=in_stream`, we may stick to the code sample from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73627720/4926757), and copy few parameters from the input stream to the output stream.

Example:

```
in_stream = test_input.streams.video[0]
codec_name = in_stream.codec_context.name  # Get the codec name from the input video stream.
fps = in_stream.codec_context.rate  # Get the framerate from the input video stream.
out_stream = test_output.add_stream(codec_name, str(fps))
out_stream.width = in_stream.codec_context.width  # Set frame width to be the same as the width of the input stream
out_stream.height = in_stream.codec_context.height  # Set frame height to be the same as the height of the input stream
out_stream.pix_fmt = in_stream.codec_context.pix_fmt  # Copy pixel format from input stream to output stream
#stream.options = {'crf': '17'}  # Select low crf for high quality (the price is larger file size).
```

---

We also have to "Mux" the video frame:

```
test_output.mux(out_packet)
```

At the end, we have to flush the encoder before closing the file:

```
out_packet = out_stream.encode(None)
test_output.mux(out_packet)
```

---

Code sample:

```
import av

# Build input_vid.mp4 using FFmpeg CLI (for testing):
# ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=100 -vcodec libx264 -crf 10 -pix_fmt yuv444p input_vid.mp4

test_input = av.open('input_vid.mp4')
test_output = av.open('output_vid.mp4', 'w')

in_stream = test_input.streams.video[0]
#out_stream = test_output.add_stream(template=in_stream)  # Using template=in_stream is not working (probably meant to be used for re-muxing and not for re-encoding).

codec_name = in_stream.codec_context.name  # Get the codec name from the input video stream.
fps = in_stream.codec_context.rate  # Get the framerate from the input video stream.
out_stream = test_output.add_stream(codec_name, str(fps))
out_stream.width = in_stream.codec_context.width  # Set frame width to be the same as the width of the input stream
out_stream.height = in_stream.codec_context.height  # Set frame height to be the same as the height of the input stream
out_stream.pix_fmt = in_stream.codec_context.pix_fmt  # Copy pixel format from input stream to output stream
#stream.options = {'crf': '17'}  # Select low crf for high quality (the price is larger file size).

for frame in test_input.decode(in_stream):
    img_frame = frame.to_image()
    out_frame = av.VideoFrame.from_image(img_frame)  # Note: to_image and from_image is not required in this specific example.
    out_packet = out_stream.encode(out_frame)  # Encode video frame
    test_output.mux(out_packet)  # "Mux" the encoded frame (add the encoded frame to MP4 file).
    print(out_packet)

# Flush the encoder
out_packet = out_stream.encode(None)
test_output.mux(out_packet)

test_input.close()
test_output.close()
```