# How to pass BytesIO image objects to ffmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, bytesio

I a have a (nested) list od BytesIO objects (images) that I would like to pass to ffmpeg and make a video. I do know, the ffmpeg cannot take it straight. What should I convert it in first? There might be a better way using 'pipe:', which I did not succeed to implement yet.
(in this example code I ignore image duration and audio, too)

```
def merge_videos(file_id: float, audio_list: List[BinaryIO], duration_list: List[float], images_nested_list):
    # flatten the nested list of images
    images_list = [image for images_sublist in images_nested_list for image in images_sublist]
    
    additional_parameters = {'c:a': 'aac', 'c:v': 'libx264'}

    # Create a BytesIO object to hold the output video data
    output_data = io.BytesIO()

    # create the FFmpeg command with the specified parameters and pipe the output to the BytesIO object
    command = ffmpeg.output(*images_list, '-', vf='fps=10,format=yuv420p', preset='veryfast', shortest=None, r=10, max_muxing_queue_size=4000, **additional_parameters).pipe(output_data)

    try:
        # run the FFmpeg command with error and output capture
        subprocess.check_output(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'concat', '-safe', '0', '-i', 'audio.txt', '-i', '-', '-c:v', 'copy', '-c:a', 'aac', f"{PROJECT_PATH}/data/final-{file_id}.mp4"], input=output_data.getvalue())
        log.info("Final video with file_id %s has been converted successfully", file_id)
```

...this code returns:

```
TypeError: Expected incoming stream(s) to be of one of the following types: ffmpeg.nodes.FilterableStream; got <class '_io.BytesIO'>
```

How to handle it please? Thanks for help.

Comment: It looks like the best option is using PyAV. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73627720/4926757) for encoding an MP4 file using PyAV. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75348681/4926757) for setting different timestamps using PyAV.